# Dividing polygon into given number of equal areas in OpenLayers

Tags: polygon, openlayers, area, splitting

I'm using a [Style](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Style.html) with [Stroke](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Stroke.html) and [Fill](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Fill.html) to have something like this for [Polygon](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon.html):

```
const feature = new Feature(
    new Polygon([
         xPos.map((x, index) => {
              return transform([parseFloat(x), parseFloat(yPos[index])], 'EPSG:3857', projection);
         })
    ])
);

feature.setStyle(
      new Style({
           stroke: new Stroke({
           color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
      }),
      fill: new Fill({color: `#${feature.getProperties().bgColor}`})
    })
 );
```

[image]

Now, I'd like to divide the polygon into a given number of equal areas (with different colors). Something like this:

[image]

What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: There is no built in functionality in OL to divide polygon into given number of equal areas. I'm also not aware of any JS library that could do this on client side in single step. There is as nice example how it can be done with turf.js library in several steps. Example is for Leaflet, but can be easily adapted to OL: https://github.com/gavinr/split-polygon-demo

Answer (score 2):

If you want to divide polygon before it's published to the web, you can use GIS tools, such as for example ArcGIS Pro (see https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/divide-a-polygon-by-a-value.htm) or QGIS with the Polygon Divider plugin (see https://github.com/jonnyhuck/RFCL-PolygonDivider).

I'm not aware of any JS library than could do this on the client side in one step. There is a nice example how this can be done in several steps with the [Turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) library in Leaflet environment: https://github.com/gavinr/split-polygon-demo. This example does not split polygon into parts of exactly the same size, it can be more than +-35%. If that's OK with you, see below how this can be done in OL.

Splitting algorithm is as follows (N is number of divided parts):

1. Create big number (let's say 5000) of random points in the bounding box of the polygon with the `turf.randomPoint` method.
2. Filter out points that fall outside of the polygon with the `turf.booleanPointInPolygon` method.
3. Group points into N clusters with the `turf.clustersKmeans` method.
4. Get centroids of clusters (calculated by turf) from cluster data.
5. Create voronoi polygons inside polygon bounding box around centroids of clusters with the `turf.voronoi` method.
6. Clip created voronoi polgygons with the polygon with the `turf.intersect` method.
7. Result are polygons that divide the original polygon into N parts, which all have similar area (+-30%, depending on the shape of the original polygon).

Code for dividing OL feature to `nDivisions` parts, where each part is coloured with one color from `colors`, could the look something like this:

```
function polygonDivide(polygonFeature, nDivisions, colors) {
  var polygon = formatGeoJSON.writeFeatureObject(polygonFeature, {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'});
  var polygonBbox = turf.bbox(polygon);

  var randomPoints = turf.randomPoint(5000, {bbox: polygonBbox});
  randomPoints.features = randomPoints.features.filter((feature) => {
    return(turf.booleanPointInPolygon(feature.geometry.coordinates, polygon));
  });

  var clusteredPoints = turf.clustersKmeans(randomPoints, {
    numberOfClusters: nDivisions,
  });
  
  var centroidPoints = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < nDivisions; i++) {
    var feature = clusteredPoints.features.find(
      function(feature) {
        return(feature.properties.cluster == i);
      }
    );
    centroidPoints[i] = turf.point(feature.properties.centroid);
  }

  var voronoiPolygons = turf.voronoi(
    {type: "FeatureCollection", features: centroidPoints},
    {bbox: polygonBbox}
  );

  var polygonArea = turf.area(polygon);
  var idealPieceArea = polygonArea / nDivisions;
  var clippedVoronoiPolygons = voronoiPolygons.features.map((feature, i) => {
    var clippedFeature = turf.intersect(feature.geometry, polygon);
    clippedFeatureArea = turf.area(clippedFeature);
    clippedFeature.properties.percentage = clippedFeatureArea / idealPieceArea;
    clippedFeature.properties.color = colors[i];
    return(clippedFeature);
  });
  clippedVoronoiPolygons = turf.featureCollection(clippedVoronoiPolygons);

  var dividedPolygonFeatures = formatGeoJSON.readFeatures(clippedVoronoiPolygons, {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'});

  return(dividedPolygonFeatures);
}
```

Here is an example how drawn polygon is divided into 8 parts after being drawn, and colored with randomly generated colors:

```
var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var sourceDrawnPolygons = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});

function style(feature) {
  var style = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: [0, 0, 255, 0.8],
      width: 1
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: feature.get('color'),
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      text: Math.floor(feature.get('percentage') * 100) + '%'
    })
  });
  return(style);
}
var formatGeoJSON = new ol.format.GeoJSON; 

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector(),
  style: style
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vectorLayer],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    zoom: 14
  })
});

var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: sourceDrawnPolygons,
  type: 'Polygon'
});
draw.on('drawend', drawEnd);     
map.addInteraction(draw);

function get_random_rgb(opacity) {
  var rgb = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 256),Math.floor(Math.random() * 256),Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)];
  return('rgb(' + rgb.join(', ') + ', ' + opacity + ')');
}

function drawEnd(e) {
  var nDivisions = 8;
  var colors = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < nDivisions; i++) {
    colors.push(get_random_rgb(0.5));
  }
  var dividedPolygonFeatures = polygonDivide(e.feature, nDivisions, colors);
  vectorLayer.getSource().addFeatures(dividedPolygonFeatures);
}
```

Here is an example of a few such divisions (percentage shown in the dividing polygon is percentage of even division):

[image]

Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/wzd2bnhv/